# How to get a SHA-1 digest of a X509 certificate with HsOpenSSL?

Tags: haskell, openssl

I'm writing a web server that accepts SSL connections and calculate a SHA-1 hash of client certificates:

```
import OpenSSL (withOpenSSL)
import OpenSSL.Session as SSL
import OpenSSL.X509 as X509
import OpenSSL.EVP.Digest as EVP

sslStuff :: SSL.SSL -> IO String
sslStuff ssl = withOpenSSL $ do
  x509   <- liftM fromJust $ SSL.getPeerCertificate ssl
  issuer <- X509.getIssuerName x509 False
  subj   <- X509.getSubjectName x509 False
  putStrLn $ "\tsubject: " ++show subj
  putStrLn $ "\tissuer: " ++show issuer
  dg <- liftM fromJust $ EVP.getDigestByName "SHA1"
  cert <- X509.printX509 x509
  putStrLn cert
  let s = EVP.digest dg cert
  putStrLn $ "After Digest: "++s
  return s
```

I successfully get the certificate, but the digest is only 15 bytes long instead of 20.
I'm not sure I correctly convert the cert to a string before passing it to EVP.digest.
Could anyone please give me an example of how to do it the right way?

Answer (score 1):

I do not know Haskell. But following code might help you.

```
X509 * x509;
char sha1dig[SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH];
/*Get X509 certificate in x509*/

//Call X509_check_purpose to set SHA1 hash.
X509_check_purpose (x509, -1, 0);

//Get the SHA1 hash into buffer. Use x509->sha1_hash
memcpy(sha1dig, x509->sha1_hash, SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH);
```

I believe that my comments will help you convert this program to convert to Haskell.